# C - error: unknown type name ‘FILE’ on Zolertia z1 motes

Tags: c, msp430, contiki

My z1 mote acts as the base station and it is connected directly to the gateway (pc). I wanted to save the data coming on a text file using this code in the unicast-receiver.c:

```
//after printing on the screen then store
FILE *f = fopen("clients.txt", "wb");
fwrite(data, sizeof(char), sizeof(data), f);
fclose(f);
```

but I am getting this error:

```
unicast-receiver.c: In function ‘receiver’:
unicast-receiver.c:49:1: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’
```

Eventhough stdio.h is included. Anyone faced the same kind of error before? How do I fix it? If there's no way to do this through z1 motes, then is any other way to store the data?

Here are the includes in the program

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "lib/random.h"
#include "sys/ctimer.h"
#include "sys/etimer.h"
#include "net/ip/uip.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip-ds6.h"
#include "net/ip/uip-debug.h"

#include "simple-udp.h"
#include "servreg-hack.h"

#include "net/rpl/rpl.h"

#include "dev/cc2420/cc2420.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Did you `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: Is your development SDK well installed?

Comment: I am using [contiki](http://zolertia.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mainpage:Contiki) that through it I can upload the program to the z1 motes. I am not sure about the SDK but supposedly it comes ready, and this is the first time I face such problem with it. @LPs

Comment: Have you got other includes before the stdio one? Post the whole file, if possible.

Comment: Oh, I have many of them actually. I will include them in the question.

Comment: Ensure that no one of those includes needs stdio.h, or simply move stdio include at the top of all includes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105812/discussion-between-ahmed-al-haddad-and-lps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msp430` is a very hardware-limited platform, so the complete C standard library functionality is not supported. In particular there is no hard disk or even SD card on typical msp430 platforms, so there's also little need to have a filesystem-related routines in software.

If you look at `msp430-libc` [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/msp430-libc/ci/master/tree/include/stdio.h), you can clearly see that it only support for the `printf` function family.

It's possible to use the `xmem` interface to store data on the onboard flash. The interface is defined in `contiki/core/dev/xmem.h`. Using it is simple: first erase a whole sector, then you can write in that sector. Call `xmem_erase` with a flash address as an argument (any address in the sector you want to erase), then call `xmem_write` passing a buffer which to write and a flash address (start offset) where write to. Flash addresses typically start from zero.

It's also possible to use the Coffee, Contiki file system.

Comment: Oh, makes sense then. How about alternative methods? Is there a way to store the data coming if I can only use the `printf` function?

Comment: You can use the `xmem` interface defined to access the flash memory directly (`contiki/core/dev/xmem.h`). FYI, you need to erase a sector before writing in it, if you know that it's pretty simple to use.

Comment: Hmm, I have to admit that I have no idea how to do that. Would you please help me, or suggest a tutorial that I can follow to do this? I tried to read data from the serial port but I have been facing a lot of bugs and it is taking me a lot more than I thought!..

Comment: Btw, do you mean to erase a sector of the memory and then store the data in the memory of the z1?

Answer (score 1):

Contiki provides a library called `CFS (Coffee flash system)` to abstract the flash memory and write/read in a file-like way, there's a guide in the [Contiki's wiki page](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/File-systems)

The Zolertia Z1 supports CFS.